# auto is not a flex-flow value

Tags: css, flexbox, w3c

Having the code:

```
.vc_tta-panels-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

But getting following error in W3C validation:

> auto is not a flex-flow value : 1 1 auto

Comment: there seems to be an open issue about this [here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2015May/0001.html)

Comment: W3C validators are not bug-free. They know this and [accept bug reports](https://validator.w3.org/feedback.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flex: 1 1 auto` is standard, as said by the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common):

> `flex: auto`. Equivalent to `flex: 1 1 auto`. Sizes the item based on
>   the [`width`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-width)/[`height`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visudet.html#propdef-height) properties, but makes them fully
>   flexible, so that they absorb any free space along the [main axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-axis).

You can just ignore the error, it's a bug of the validator. Alternatively, use the equivalent `flex: auto`, which is accepted as valid.

Comment: How can put this equivalent as 'auto' is not value of property?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam `auto` is a possible value of the [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) property. And [`flex-basis`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis) accepts `<width>` values. And [`flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) accepts `<flex-basis>` values. So you can use `flex: auto`.